# Orientation preserving parametrisation of torus

Tags: differential-geometry, orientation

**EDIT**: *After having posted the question along with an attempt at a solution, I could spot the mistake in my solution (it's easier to read LaTeX than your own imperfect handwriting...), so now it is solved and I will post my solution as an answer, while I only leave the main question in the main post. Of course I'm more than happy to accept an alternative solution.*

I'll be referring to Lee's Intro to Smooth Manifolds book whenever citing a result. I'm tackling Problem 16-2.

Consider the torus $\mathbb T^2=S^1\times S^1\subset\mathbb R^4$. Write an arbitrary element of $\mathbb R^4$ as $(x^1,x^2,x^3,x^4)$. Consider the $2$-form $\omega=x^2 x^3x^4 dx^1\wedge dx^3$. I need to compute
$$
\int_{\mathbb T^2}\omega.
$$
Let $p:(0,2/pi)\to S^1-\{(0,1)\},t\mapsto e^{it}$. Consider the parametrization
$$
p\times p:(0,2\pi)\times(0,2\pi)\to \mathbb T^2,(t,s)\mapsto (e^{it},e^{is}).
$$
I would like to show that this parametrization is orientation preserving, so that I can invoke Proposition 16.8. However, I have difficulty showing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By proposition 15.7 we can consider orientations forms $\omega_1,\omega_2$ on $S^1$, and then $\pi_1^*\omega_1\wedge\pi_2^*\omega_2$ will be an orientation form on $S^1\times S^1$. Since $S^1$ is a hypersurface in $\mathbb R^2$, we know by Proposition 15.21 that if we take an orientation form $\eta_1$ on $\mathbb R^2$,  then $\iota^*(N\lrcorner\omega)$ will be an orientation form of $S^1$. Take $dx^1\wedge dx^2$ as orientation form on $\mathbb R^2$. Then
$$
\iota^*(N\lrcorner dx^1\wedge dx^2)=x^1 dx^2-x^2 dx^1.
$$
Similarly we find an orientation form for the other factor of the torus. This then yields
$$
\pi_1^*(x^1 dx^2-x^2 dx^1)\wedge \pi_2^*(x^3 dx^4-x^4 dx^3)=(x^1 dx^2-x^2 dx^1)\wedge (x^3 dx^4-x^4 dx^3)
$$
as orientation form on $S^1\times S^1$. Let's call this form $\eta$. Using coordinates $(t,s)$ on $(0,2\pi)^2$, if we pull back along $p\times p$ we get
$$
(p\times p)^*\eta=(\cos t\, d\sin t-\sin t\, d\cos t)\wedge(\cos s\, d\sin s-\sin s\, d\cos s)
$$
which is equal to
$$
(\cos^2 t+\sin^2 t)(\cos^2 s+\sin^2 s)dt\wedge ds=dt\wedge ds.
$$
Note that this is an orientation form on $(0,2\pi)\times (0,2\pi)$ and therefore $p\times p$ is orientation preserving by Exercise 15.13. Computing the integral now is straightforward.

*Cleaner solution:*

Here is a similar solution using that $p$ is a coordinate chart. Let's first describe an orientation form on $S^1$ in terms of the chart $p$. Note that $p$ has to be either orientation preserving or reversing, since $(0,2\pi)$ is connected. Consider the oriented frame $\partial_t$ on $(0,2\pi)$. We have that
$$
T_tp \partial_t=-\sin t \partial_x + \cos t\partial_y,
$$
which is positively oriented (by Prop 15.21 a frame $X$ for $S^1$ is oriented iff $(N,X)$ is oriented), and hence $p$ is orientation preserving. Let $\theta=p^{-1}$. Then $d\theta=(p^{-1})^*dt$, which is by construction an orientation form. Denoting the same form on the other factor of the torus by $d\phi$, we find that $d\theta\wedge d\phi$ is an orientation form on $S^1\times S^1$, and by construction we have that
$$
(p\times p)^*d\theta\wedge d\psi=dt\wedge ds
$$
is an orientation form, and hence $p\times p$ is orientation preserving. (Note that $p\times p$ would have been orientation preserving even if $p$ was orientation reserving, but it's nice to know that $p$ is orientation preserving - as it should be!)

Comment: Even easier, $dt$ and $ds$ are each positively-oriented, so $dt\wedge ds$ is a positively-oriented area form on the product.

Comment: @TedShifrin I just realised a simpler solution indeed, and I was about to write it out! :)